# How does a module overwrite a method in the parent class of a class in which it is included?

Tags: ruby

I am trying to write a module that overwrites an instance method in the class it is included in.

This doesn't work:

```
require 'active_support'

class Foo
  def bar
    "bar"
  end
end

module NewFoo
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    alias __bar__ bar
  end

  def bar
    "new " + __bar__
  end
end

class Baz < Foo
  include NewFoo
end
```

My expectation is that `Baz.new.bar.should eql "new bar"` but instead I get a `undefined local variable or method '__bar__'` error.

I have tried variations of the above, including the old way via `def self.include(base)...` to no avail.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's this great new invention called *inheritance*:

```
module NewFoo
  def bar
    'new ' + super
  end
end
```

Or more idiomatically

```
"new #{super}"
```

Comment: Doh. We had been staring at our screen for too long. Thnx.

Comment: @hakanensari: I know the feeling. I once spent an entire morning mucking around with some complicated looping logic, trying to figure out the most elegant way to do an `inject` which does the same thing for every element except the last one. Then a friend catches one glimpse of the code and says: "You *do* know that's just `Array#join`, right?"